# scrapy response.xpath() cause memory leaking

Tags: xpath, memory-leaks, scrapy

i found response.xpath() method leaking memory while using scrapy to write a spider. here is the code:

```
def extract_data(self, response):
    aomen_host_water = None
    aomen_pankou = None
    aomen_guest_water = None
    sb_host_water = None
    sb_pankou = None
    sb_guest_water = None


    # response.xpath('//div[@id="webmain"]/table[@id="odds"]/tr')
    # for tr in all_trs:
    #     # cname(company name)
    #     cname = tr.xpath('td[1]/text()').extract()
    #     if len(cname) == 0:
    #         continue
    #     # remove extra space and other stuff
    #     cname = cname[0].split(' ')[0]
    #     if cname == u'澳彩':
    #         aomen_host_water = tr.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
    #         if len(aomen_host_water) != 0:
    #             aomen_pankou = tr.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()
    #             aomen_guest_water = tr.xpath('td[11]/text()').extract()
    #         else:
    #             aomen_host_water = tr.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract()
    #             aomen_pankou = tr.xpath('td[7]/text()').extract()
    #             aomen_guest_water = tr.xpath('td[8]/text()').extract()
    #     elif cname == u'ＳＢ':
    #         sb_host_water = tr.xpath('td[9]/text()').extract()
    #         if len(sb_host_water) != 0:
    #             sb_pankou = tr.xpath('td[10]/text()').extract()
    #             sb_guest_water = tr.xpath('td[11]/text()').extract()
    #         else:
    #             sb_host_water = tr.xpath('td[6]/text()').extract()
    #             sb_pankou = tr.xpath('td[7]/text()').extract()
    #             sb_guest_water = tr.xpath('td[8]/text()').extract()
    # if (aomen_host_water is None) or (aomen_pankou is None) or (aomen_guest_water is None) or \
    #         (sb_host_water is None) or (sb_pankou is None) or (sb_guest_water is None):
    #     return None
    # if (len(aomen_host_water) == 0) or (len(aomen_pankou) == 0) or (len(aomen_guest_water) == 0) or \
    #         (len(sb_host_water) == 0) or (len(sb_pankou) == 0) or (len(sb_guest_water) == 0):
    #     return None
    # item = YPItem()
    # item['aomen_host_water'] = float(aomen_host_water[0])
    # item['aomen_pankou'] = aomen_pankou[0].encode('utf-8')  # float(pankou.pankou2num(aomen_pankou[0]))
    # item['aomen_guest_water'] = float(aomen_guest_water[0])
    # item['sb_host_water'] = float(sb_host_water[0])
    # item['sb_pankou'] = sb_pankou[0].encode('utf-8') # float(pankou.pankou2num(sb_pankou[0]))
    # item['sb_guest_water'] = float(sb_guest_water[0])

    item = YPItem()
    item['aomen_host_water'] = 1.0
    item['aomen_pankou'] = '111'  # float(pankou.pankou2num(aomen_pankou[0]))
    item['aomen_guest_water'] = 1.0
    item['sb_host_water'] = 1.0
    item['sb_pankou'] = '111' # float(pankou.pankou2num(sb_pankou[0]))
    item['sb_guest_water'] = 1.0
    return item
```

here i commented the useful statements and used fake data, spider used about 45M memory, when i uncommented the commented lines, spider used 100+M memory and the memory usage continuously rises. Did somebody met this kind of problem before ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might decrease the memory usage by switching to `extract_first()` instead of `extract()` which would create unnecessary lists.

I would also upgrade `scrapy` and `lxml` to the latest versions:

```
pip install --upgrade scrapy
pip install --upgrade lxml
```

Comment: i tried just uncomment the first line, the spider's memory usage is still high and  rises continuously

Comment: @bob sure, have you seen the http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/leaks.html page?

Comment: yes, i saw the page and used prefs() and guppy's hpy.heap(), i saw no memory leaks.

Comment: i'm new to python, but, most of the variables are local, and there is no cross-reference. i don't know why there is still memory leaks.

Comment: @bob hey man, I am having exact same issue. Did you manage to fix it?